# Pagination : Remove element using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pagination

I have a section where i have to paginate records.
Now the issue is the number gets added but i want to remove the prev number

I have currently having something as below:

Prev 1 2 3 Next

When i click on next 4 gets added and it becomes
Prev 1 2 3 4 Next

When i click on next again 5 gets added and it becomes
Prev 1 2 3 4 5 Next

**What i am trying to do and what should be having**

Prev 1 2 3 Next

When i click on next 4 gets added and it should become
Prev 2 3 4 Next

When i click on next again 5 gets added and it becomes
Prev 3 4 5 Next

When i click on Previous Now it should be
Prev 2 3 4 Next

Please find my runnable code below:

```js
$('ul.pagination').on('click', 'a', function() { // listen for click on pagination link
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
  
    var active_elm = $('ul.pagination a.active');
  
    if(this.id == 'next'){
      var _next = active_elm.parent().next().children('a');
      if($(_next).attr('id') == 'next') {
        
        // appending next button if reach end
        var num = parseInt($('a.active').text())+1;
        active_elm.removeClass('active');
        $('<li><a class="active" href="#">'+num+'</a></li>').insertBefore($('#next').parent());
        return; 
      }
      _next.addClass('active');   
      
      
      
      
    }
    else if(this.id == 'prev') {
      var _prev = active_elm.parent().prev().children('a');
      if($(_prev).attr('id') == 'prev') return false;
      _prev.addClass('active');   
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    active_elm.removeClass('active');
    
});
```

```css
ul.pagination {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.pagination li {display: inline;}

ul.pagination li a {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: background-color .3s;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

ul.pagination li a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #4CAF50;
}

ul.pagination li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #ddd;}

div.center {text-align: center;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a id="prev">«</a></li>
    <li><a id="test1" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a id="test2" class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="next">»</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have added the html as well

Comment: http://paginationjs.com/

Comment: Added the snippet.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679611/next-prev-in-jquery-list-to-show-only-5-and-hide-others

Comment: @sTg you only wanted 3 page buttons limit?

Comment: @NewbeeDev Yes i have mentioned the requirement

Comment: Here is a start: `var $first = $("#prev").parent().next();
      _next = $first.find("a");_next.text(num);
      $first.insertBefore($('#next').parent());`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I would do it.
I would add a class to the 3 `<li>` tags with the numbers inside for easy access with the jQuery selector.
Inside the if-statement where you check weather the next button has the id `next`, remove the first child like so:

```
$('.three_links').first().remove();
```

and add the next number after the last child like so:

```
$('.three_links').last().after('<li class="three_links"><a class="active" href="#">'+num+'</a></li>');
```

and if the id is `prev` remove the last child and add the previous number before the first child but only if the previous number is greater than `1`:

```
if(num > 0){
    active_elm.removeClass('active');
    $('.three_links').last().remove();
    $('.three_links').first().before('<li class="three_links"><a class="active" href="#">'+num+'</a></li>');
}
```

[Here is a working jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/srshjb1z/)

html:

```
<div class="center">
    <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#" id="prev">«</a></li>
        <li class="three_links"><a id="test1" href="#">1</a></li>
        <li class="three_links"><a id="test2" class="active" href="#">2</a></li>
        <li class="three_links"><a id="test3" href="#">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="next">»</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('ul.pagination').on('click', 'a', function() { // listen for click on pagination link
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;

    var active_elm = $('ul.pagination a.active');

    if(this.id == 'next'){
        var _next = active_elm.parent().next().children('a');
        if($(_next).attr('id') == 'next') {

            // appending next button if reach end
            var num = parseInt($('a.active').text())+1;
            active_elm.removeClass('active');
            $('.three_links').first().remove();
            $('.three_links').last().after('<li class="three_links"><a class="active" href="#">'+num+'</a></li>');
            return; 
        }
        _next.addClass('active');   
    }
    else if(this.id == 'prev') {
        var _prev = active_elm.parent().prev().children('a');
        if($(_prev).attr('id') == 'prev'){
            var num = parseInt($('a.active').text())-1;
            if(num > 0){
                active_elm.removeClass('active');
                $('.three_links').last().remove();
                $('.three_links').first().before('<li class="three_links"><a class="active" href="#">'+num+'</a></li>');
            }
            return;
        }
        _prev.addClass('active');   
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    active_elm.removeClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this after adding next number

```
$('#prev').parent().next().remove();
```

[Codepen http://codepen.io/mastersmind/pen/ZBJZjo](http://codepen.io/mastersmind/pen/ZBJZjo)

Comment: How should i go for previous?

Answer (score 1):

Use below script:

```
$('ul.pagination').on('click', 'a', function() { // listen for click on pagination link
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;

    var active_elm = $('ul.pagination a.active');

    if(this.id == 'next'){
      var _next = active_elm.parent().next().children('a');
      if($(_next).attr('id') == 'next') {

        // appending next button if reach end
        var num = parseInt($('a.active').text())+1;
        active_elm.removeClass('active');
        $('<li><a class="active" href="#">'+num+'</a></li>').insertBefore($('#next').parent());
        var hidenum = parseInt($('a.active').text())-2;
        if(hidenum > 0){
            $('#next').parent().prev().prev().prev().prev().hide();
        }
        return; 
      }
      _next.addClass('active');   




    }
    else if(this.id == 'prev') {
      var _prev = active_elm.parent().prev().children('a');
      if($(_prev).attr('id') == 'prev') return false;
      _prev.addClass('active'); 
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
    }
    active_elm.removeClass('active');

});
```